# Php equivalent needed for python snippet with Xpath custom extension

Tags: python, php, xpath

I am stuck with porting a huge python code to php 8

It's using xpath custom functions inside.

Need help with below code explanation, and even better if someone can give a PHP equivalent.

Common initialization.

```
import html5lib
from html5lib import HTMLParser
from lxml import etree, html, cssselect

def _html5lib_parser() -> HTMLParser:
    return HTMLParser(
        html5lib.treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("lxml"),
        namespaceHTMLElements=False
    )


html_message=html5parser.document_fromstring(s,parser=_html5lib_parser())
```

Snippet 1: Xpath with user defined function

```
def text_content(context):
    """XPath Extension to return text content of a node"""
    return context.context_node.xpath("string()").strip()


block = html_message.xpath(
    ("//*[starts-with(mg:text_content(), 'From:')]|"
     "//*[starts-with(mg:text_content(), 'Date:')]"))
         
         
if block:
    block = block[-1]
    parent_div = None
```

Snippet 2: Xpath with another user defined function

```
def tail(context):
    """XPath Extension function to return tail text of a node"""
    return context.context_node.tail or ''

block = html_message.xpath(
        ("//*[starts-with(mg:tail(), 'From:')]|"
         "//*[starts-with(mg:tail(), 'Date:')]"))
if block:
    block = block[0]
```

I am using DomDocument with Xpath till now for rest of the code in Php

```
$html_message = new DOMDocument();
$html_message->loadHTML($html_string);

$finder = new DomXPath($html_message);
$node = $finder->query();
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's the problem. Python code is already existing and working. I need to make it work in PHP :)

Comment: Don't port the code. Port the intention: what is the python code suppose to do. So, rather than "what does its source code look like", "what output is this supposed to yield, given which input". Then implement _that_ in PHP, using all the modern libraries available to you. There's a bunch of html5 and DOM parsers available, you don't have to mirror the code that was written back when it had to be done in python.